# awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file2split FNR=1666) fatal: can't redirect to `CCTGGCAG_GATATAAC_HAP1' (Operation not permitted)

Tags: awk

I wanted to split a file into multiple files based on its first column value, using `zcat file2split.gz | awk '{print>$1}'`, but encountered the following error:

`` awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file2split FNR=1666) fatal: can't redirect to `CCTGGCAG_GATATAAC_HAP1' (Operation not permitted) ``

Any idea for that? Thanks!

The zip data is 25Mb in size and can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qjq-ibdiyemBfuqpoC2h0VDhw09PS0ao/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The command was able to generate some files indeed, but then it outputed the error

Comment: Which awk and version number? GNU/awk should write to any number of files (although once it exceeds the `ulimit -n` openfiles limit (typically 1024) it starts a close/reopen/append strategy that ruins performance). Other awks choke on more than 1024 open files. It seems to me that 1666 input lines might easily correspond to 1024 distinct filenames. How many files did you get written to?

Comment: I am using GNU Awk 4.0.2. The program generated 1006 files then broke

Comment: My best guess is you have an existing file with that name and simply don't have write permission for it or, probably a bit less likely, you ran out of storage space on your device. If that's not it, if you're on a Mac, maybe it's this: https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/? Otherwise - what happens if you just run `awk 'BEGIN{print "foo" > "CCTGGCAG_GATATAAC_HAP1"}'`? Can you apply divide and conquer to the input file to get to the specific line(s) causing the problem?

Comment: Not really. I am on Linux server and was creating new files indeed

Comment: see my other questions in that comment

Comment: [I posted a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665297/133219) for you to try that will create the output files 1 at a time and in a different order. Does it still fail? If yes then the problem is not too many concurrently open output files, and - does it fail at the same input line number `1666` or at the same output file name `CCTGGCAG_GATATAAC_HAP1` or somewhere completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid running into open-files limits by closing the previous filename whenever the current output filename changes.  e.g.

```
awk '{ out=$1;
       if (out != lastfile) {
         if (lastfile != "") { close(lastfile) };
         lastfile = out
     };
     print > out'
```

This is significantly better than closing the file and re-opening it on **every** write.  It only closes the file when the filename has changed since the immediately last write.  If the file happens to be sorted by field 1, it will never have to re-open a file...and if it's "mostly sorted", it will rarely have to re-open a file.

Note: if the same filename may occur more than once on **non-adjacent** lines, then you should append the output with `print >> out` instead of `print > out`, otherwise when the file is **re-opened** for write, it will be completely over-written (i.e. truncated to zero size) before that write.

(BTW, this is one of the reasons why `awk` doesn't automatically close the file after each write.  The other main reason, of course, is that it's much slower to close and re-open the same files for every write if you don't have to)

This is only a little more complicated if you want to overwrite the file the first time it is seen an any given run of the awk script, but append if the same file is seen again in the same run.  e.g.

```
awk '{ out=$1;
       if (out != lastfile) {
         if (lastfile != "") { close(lastfile) };
         lastfile = out
     };

     if (seen[out]++) {
       print >> out
     } else {
       print > out
     }'
```

This version uses associative array `seen` to keep track of whether we've seen a filename before or not.  If yes, append. if not, overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if too many concurrently open files is really causing your current problem but FYI the robust, efficient way to do what you're trying to do is the following using GNU sort for `-s` and any awk:

```
zcat file2split.gz |
sort -s -k1,1 |
awk '
    $1 != out {
        close(out)
        out = $1
    }
    { print > out }
'
```

If you don't have GNU sort you can do the same with any version of these standard Unix tools:

```
zcat file2split.gz |
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print NR, $0}' |
sort -k2,2 -k1,1n |
cut -f2- |
awk '
    $1 != out {
        close(out)
        out = $1
    }
    { print > out }
'
```

With the above approach of sorting the input before awk starts creating output files, awk only ever has 1 output file open at a time and never has to open an output file more than once, it just opens it, writes **all** associated lines to it, then closes it and moves on to the next output file.

Comment: Hi Ed, I tried the first one and it worked! And the sort indeed made it more efficient

Comment: Glad to hear it, then I suggest you update to the latest gawk version, 5.1.0, as maybe you're hitting a bug in your old version (and you are missing several bug fixes and new features).